# How to run procedure on Form Close but not on Form Edit

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

In my VBA Form's code, I want to call a procedure when the form is closed, but I don't want it to run if I enter Design View.

How can I distinguish in my code?

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
     'If NotFormEdit then   <--or something?
     Call MyProcedure()
End Sub
```

The code errors when I enter Design View because it expects to fetch data from the form before exiting, but it can't do that when it enters Design View.

Normally, I am the only one to enter Design View, but the procedure still needs to run when other users close the form.

I know I can throw the error and get by, and I know that's not the right practice.

If there is no way to distinguish between *form close* and *enter form Design View*, then what else could I do?

Comment: You mean when you switch to Design view? You can't distinguish these events, I think.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish via an error?

Comment: Do you have users switching to Design View while in Edit Mode? Or is just you?

Comment: No, just me; but sometimes if I do something in a pinch it is confusing.  I don't understand why someone downvoted my question; what's wrong with it?

Comment: If it's just you - put a check in for current Username using Environ or GetNetworkUser API call - only run the code if the username is NOT yours

Comment: i haven't down voted yet, but your question is unclear. Can you elaborate litte more? maybe use the correct terminology. When you say edit mode do you mean by design view? if you are in form view and switching to design view, form_close_Event will fire. If you are closing a form from design view, that event will **NOT** fire. Since form_close even will only complete after processing your "myprocedure", your procedure will never get the chance to know if your form's.currentview is design view. so your argument "it can't do that when it enters edit mode" is invalid..

Comment: Fact: When I enter Design View then I get an error on that procedure which normally runs when I close the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a lot clearer now.

I think the only way to do it is to test the form state in your called procedure. But for me (Access 2010), the Close event and the called procedure runs and finishes **before** the switch to Design view is actually done.

(Edit: I just noticed that this is basically what Krish wrote in his comment above.)

```
Public Sub MyProcedure()

    ' Is form loaded?
    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, "frmStart") = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Form is not loaded!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Form_frmStart.CurrentView = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Form is opened in Design view!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' This is reached and works for me if I switch frmStart to Design view!
    MsgBox Form_frmStart.product

End Sub
```

If this doesn't help, please add the code of `MyProcedure()` to your question, and specify the error location and message.